# Customer Service Hub issue on Case entity form for Related section

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365-v9, interactive-service-hub

I have an issue while working with CRM Dynamics 365 v9.0 in Customer Service Hub as how to get the icon beside the "Related Section" of Case form for the Interactive experience like below image:

[image]

1. To see the list of related cases
2. Entitlements
3. Knowledge base search

Please suggest if we have any OOB feature to enable this.
Your suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Reference panel - It’s a new type of section we can insert into form, especially Customer service hub (aka. Interactive service hub) shows this further tabbed navigation.

> A new type of section called “reference panel” can also be added. A reference panel is a single column section. You can insert sub grids, quick view control, or a Knowledge Base Search control inside a reference panel section. Each control that you added in the reference panel appears as a vertical tab within the reference panel at the runtime. You can drag and drop the various controls within the reference panel section. The default tab at the runtime is the first control added in the reference panel. The other tabs appear in the order in which they are added in the form editor. To delete a tab, use the Delete key on your keyboard.
>   When you insert a reference panel, by default it’s added as a last section in the tab. You can add only one reference panel per form.

[Read more](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt622060.aspx#Section%20properties)

[image]